# How to make hierarchical facet labels in ggpairs?

Tags: r, facet, ggally, ggpairs

I'm working on a pairs plot where I want to use hierarchical facet labels.
`ggpairs` takes its facet labels from the column names of the input data.frame or from the `columnLabels`-argument. However, from these options I don't see a way to apply an extra level of column labels.

What I want:
[image]

I know it is possible with an ordinary `facet_grid` plot, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59184870/12785645), but I don't get how it would work with ggpairs.

So far, all I could think of is just splitting the names in two lines:

```
newlabs <- iris %>% 
  select(1:4) %>% 
  colnames() %>% 
  str_replace(pattern = '\\.', replacement = '\n')

ggpairs(iris, 
        columns = 1:4, 
        columnLabels = newlabs,
        upper = list(continuous = 'points'),
        diag = 'blank')
```